# Difference between shared preference and sqlite

Tags: android

I know this topic has been discussed before on Stack Overflow. But there are still some things that are not clear when I read previous posts about it. So here they are:

- I know that we use shared preference for small datasets and sqlite for large data manipulation, so if we just want to save a username and password should we use shared preferences?
- Won't shared preferences be lost when user uninstalls the app? For example I download an app called abc and save my username and password. Then I uninstall this app from one phone and try to access it from other phone using the same username and password. Will this be saved using shared preferences or the data be lost?
- What are the main reason we use one over the other beside large and small datasets?

Comment: i've question too! i want to store some strings and ints data, that users fill them (i want to store unlimited items numbers). please help me which of  them is better for  this case? thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can think of the difference between shared preferences and an SQLite database in terms of data size but that isn't entirely accurate. A better way to think of it is in terms of the structure of the data you want to store.

Shared preferences can only store key-value pairings whilst an SQLite database is much more flexible. So shared preferences are particularly useful for storing user preferences, e.g. should the app display notifications etc. Whilst an SQLite database is useful for just about anything.

Both data sources are local but something you should be aware of is the ability to backup your application data to cloud storage that is linked to the user's Google account. This makes it much easier for your users to change devices and for their applications to easily transfer to the new device. For more info take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html).

Answer (score 4):

In the situation you described about you will lose the user name and password in both situations.  The data is stored on the phone, when you uninstall the application, the data that some with it will also be lost.  The user will have to re-enter this information.

You can save the user name and pass in either the shared Preferences or a DB, that is personal preference.  Just make sure you lock either down, i.e. don't share the DB or Shared Preferences that you keep this information in.

As for the difference... shared Preferences should hold well... shared Preferences... here is an example:

If I create an option to change the background color, I will store all available options in a DB that can be loaded into a adapter view for the user to choose from.  But I will store the color that they have selected in the Shared Preferences.  This way when the application load I can get the Shared Preference value of the background color that should be used.

Answer (score 3):

`SharedPreferences` is used for just that, storing user preferences shared application-wide. You can use it, for example, to store a user's username, or perhaps some options he or she has configured in your app in which you want to remember.

SQLite is a relational *database*. It's used to store your application's data, not preferences or configuration information.

Both are stored locally on the device.

Comment: So what do we use to make sure we have username and password even after user uninstalls the app?

Comment: use a webserver that your app connects to and save the data there.

Answer (score 3):

1.SharedPreferences  stores only Boolean, int, float, long, String five kinds of simple data types, such as can not be conditional query. So, whether SharedPreferences data storage operation is how simple it can only be a supplement of storage, but can not completely replace other data such as the SQLite database is stored.

2.SharedPreferences based on the XML file to store key-value key used to store configuration information(mainly user preference for your application).

3.Sharedprefrece just like  `cookies` in web which store some basic information at client side.

Answer (score 1):

both store their data locally, so uninstalling the app will delete both. other than that, SharedPreferences is easier to program, and you're right about the data amounts.

Comment: So even with sqlite i wont be able to save data? How do you save data then? What is the point of using these if you cannot save or retrieve username and passwords?

Comment: you can save the data, as long as the user doesn't delete the app. If you want the data to persist if the user deletes and reinstalls the app, you need to set up you a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

In general, shared preferences should be used if you want to allow your user to directly manipulate certain data fields. Shared preferences are basically user preferences; if you would like the user to reconfigure the app to behave in different ways, you should expose that functionality as a shared preference. On the other hand, the SQLite database should be used if you want to limit the visibility of the data to just the application, if you want a stronger guarantee that the data be persistent, and if you want the application to behave independently of what is stored in the database. Of course, you can use both in one application.

Shared preferences and the database are part of local data that the application stores. If you uninstall the application, both of the data stores will be removed.