# Which is a better way to store custom array list in local memory in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, local-storage, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have already used `SharedPreferences`. But i want to find better way to save and retrieve Arraylist in android.

I have tried to save details in SQLite but sqlite is only for structured details. I am confused which local storage will be proper way to Arraylist.

Please give the proper reason which we have to use in which scenario.

Comment: Use Room DataBase to store data in the local database, it is easy and no boilerplate code like SQlite.

Comment: Thanks @farhana i will use Room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes If you have long data with multiple filed then you have to store in SQLite database. In SQLite database, no need to create multiple fields in the database just convert ArrayList to string and store it to the database. when you retrieve data from the database as a string, convert a string to ArralyList. This is easy, secure and fastest way to store data in local.

The Convention String to ArrayList of class and ArrayList of class to string you should be used GSON.

Happy coding ....

Comment: Sqlite is better way than ShredPreferences why?

Comment: You can think of the difference between shared preferences and an SQLite database in terms of data size but that isn't entirely accurate. A better way to think of it is in terms of the structure of the data you want to store.Shared preferences can only store key-value pairings whilst an SQLite database is much more flexible. So shared preferences are particularly useful for storing user preferences, e.g. should the app display notifications etc. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590685/difference-between-shared-preference-and-sqlite

Comment: @paras better to go with Room instead of Sqllite.

Comment: Thanks @PratikSatani data base is better than shared preferences.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both `SharedPreferences` and `SQLite`. To save convert your arraylist to `json` like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String yourJsonString = gson.toJson(arrayList);
```

And to retrieve

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourObject>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<YourObject> arrayList =  gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, type);
```

Comment: I know but my question which is better way and why?

Comment: If you have large arraylist try `Realm`. It's very fast than sql database.